# Limit Signal/Label to first occurence

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to find a way to display only the first occurence of each Signal/Label and connect them.
I've tried with barssince and everything I can think of...

**Task definition:**
The first label must be a GREEN label
Only display the first occurence of GREEN or RED label
So the second label must be a RED label, third a GREEN and so on.

Here is an Example which displays too much signals:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXEZw.png)

```
//@version=4
study("LabelTest", overlay=true)
GREEN = rsi(close, 14) < 30
RED = rsi(close, 14) > 70

if(GREEN)
    label.new(bar_index, na, yloc=yloc.belowbar, color=color.green, style=label.style_label_up)

if(RED)
    label.new(bar_index, na, yloc=yloc.abovebar, color=color.red, style=label.style_label_down)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it ;)

```
//@version=4
study("LabelTest", overlay=true)
GREEN = rsi(close, 14) < 38
RED = rsi(close, 14) > 62

lastState = if(GREEN)
    "GREEN"
else if (RED)
    "RED"
    
if(GREEN and lastState[1]=="RED")
    label.new(bar_index, na, yloc=yloc.belowbar, color=color.green, style=label.style_label_up)

if(RED and lastState[1]=="GREEN")
    label.new(bar_index, na, yloc=yloc.abovebar, color=color.red, style=label.style_label_down)
```